# Distribution of the number of trials until the last arrival in a Bernoulli process before an arbitrary point in time $t$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I was looking at a problem in the book Introduction to probability by Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis (problem 5 ch. 6) but I got confused by the solution.

Without addressing the details of the problem, suppose that, in a Bernoulli process with parameter $p$, you observe a failure at time $t$. Let $M$ be the number of the last win before time $t$ and $N$ be the number of the next win after time $t$.

Now $X = N-t$ follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p$. The solution argues that $Y = t-M$ is also geometrically distributed with the same parameter "by symmetry and independence of the games". However I'm not sure I understand the last part.

Is it just assumed that $t$ is infinitely large for convenience? If so how could we answer upon the distribution of $Y$ if $t$ was given a specific value?

Comment: What is a win, and how is it related to a failure? How are the numbers assigned? Separately to wins and failures or or consecutively to wins and failures, so that if $M < t-1$, we can assume that trials $M+1, M+2, \ldots, t$ all resulted in failure?

Comment: @DilipSarwate There is an infinite sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots$ of independent random variables following the bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$. A trial in time $i$ (or the trial of number $i$) is $X_i$ and is a success/win if $X_i = 1$ and failure otherwise. So, as you mentioned, trials $M+1,M+2,\dots,t$ all resulted in failure. As I mentioned in the post $t$ is the trial we observed the failure, and is arbitrary (it's like if the process was already happening and you suddenly decided to look at $X_t$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a couple hours after I posted the question I realised the answer, so I'm answering it here for completeness.

The problem apparently assumes that $t$ is a point after an infinite amount of time of the bernoulli process, so $Y$ is indeed geometrically  distributed.

This results in an interesting concept which is known as the **The Random Incidence Paradox**.

As for when $t$ was given a specific non-infinite value, then the distribution of $Y$ is the like asking the distribution of the number of trials until the first success given that the number is less than $t$, but I'm not going to go into details regarding that.